# ASP.NET project works locally on build when VS is running but not on IIS on my local machine or my server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7.5, windows-server-2012-r2

I published my asp.net (net core app 2.1) to windows 2012 r2 at localhost::80.
It gives me the following error:

---

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       Unknown
Handler    Not yet determined
Error Code     0x8007000d
Config Error
Config File    \web.config
Requested URL      :80/
Physical Path
Logon Method       Not yet determined
Logon User     Not yet determined

---

As far as I checked, the error seems to be in web.config
I'll put the web.config in the code section.

I have tried deleting the web.config and enabling directory browsing, making an index.html load index.cshtml but that won't work because MVC.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <!-- Remove WebDAV module so that we can make DELETE requests -->
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <!-- Remove WebDAV module so that we can make DELETE requests -->
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <!-- When deploying on Azure, make sure that "dotnet" is installed and the path to it is registered in the PATH environment variable or specify the full path to it -->
    <aspNetCore requestTimeout="23:00:00" processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" startupTimeLimit="3600">
      <environmentVariables />
    </aspNetCore>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I expected it to start but as it happens I get the error.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: When you remote in to server can you open IIS Manager, find your website listed under the 'Sites' and successfully browse the website from IIS?

Comment: All of the above but cannot browse it.
500.19 error.

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html You can run a report to learn why, but most likely you forgot to install ASP.NET Core module, just like many other threads on SO.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for the answer!
As it happens, I installed aspnetcore module on local machine and it still throws the error.

Comment: You should now see a 502.5 error, as you give wrong values for processPath and arguments.

Comment: @LexLi
Hi!
Yes I did. Is that a positive sign?
Where do I move from here? (This is my first asp.net project)
Also, as a side, I am a huge fan of your work and only now realized who you are.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and I solved it by installing URL Rewrite using the Web Platform Installer in the IIS manager.